# ios Safari is chopping off "www" from $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], how is this possible

Tags: php, ios, safari, hostname, lightopenid

Having a separate mobile site on a subdomain which has the name `m.domain` instead of `domain`:

When I try to login on ios devices with openid I get an error page from google but not if I use the site from my desktop.

chrome mobile is ok, it is just safari.
I thought those server variables would stay the same no matter what?

Can someone explain that?

**EDIT:**
There really is not much to output in the form of an error except that openid needs to have the "www" in it's authorization request because I compared the strings. It errors in the "realm" variable wich is set by "SERVER['HTTP_HOST']" in the lightopenid library.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with your login forms structure, rather than `$_SERVER` variables as they are provided by the server, and since you are trying to log into the same server, all outcome should be identical no-matter what device you are using.

Comment: so, how Is it possible to use the site without error from a desktop

Comment: Why don't you just echo `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and see it from all devices, instead of trying the login form? The problem can only be with the form

Comment: I do not really see your point, it is all the same code(it is the same site) and I already echoed it, that's why I know why I have this error. My only question is how is this possible IF ITS THE SAME CODE?

Comment: weird, I better test for it  with strpos

Comment: I am not sure, really sure what to tell you, sounds weird. Can you output the error in your question, so everyone can see?

Comment: there really is not much to output except that openid needs to have the "www" in it's authorization request because I compared the strings, but I will add this to the question